# Matching less than 6cM on Ancestry but almost 15cM at GEDmatch

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, gedmatch.com

I am communicating with someone who appears to be a 5th cousin once removed.  According to AncestryDNA my cousin shares 10cM across 1 segment with my paternal uncle, but is not a match to me (at least not above the 6cM cutoff).

However, when my cousin's and my AncestryDNA is uploaded and compared at GEDmatch we find that we share 14.7cM in one segment on Chromosome 5.

Is a discrepancy like this between the two sites based on the same two test results able to be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @ColeValleyGirl](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/16306/matching-less-than-6cm-on-ancestry-but-almost-15cm-at-gedmatch#comment25648_16306), I think the answer to this lies in [Filtering DNA matches at AncestryDNA with Timber](https://blogs.ancestry.com/ancestry/2015/06/08/filtering-dna-matches-at-ancestrydna-with-timber/):

> Longer identical segments don’t necessarily prove that two people have
>   a recent common ancestor.  DNA matching among hundreds of thousands of
>   people has shown that even long identical segments can indicate shared
>   ancestry, shared population history, or a more distant shared
>   ancestor.
>
> The good news is that by using a filter like Timber, we can find
>   shared DNA that is more likely to be due to recent common ancestors.

I suspect that the shared segment of 14.7 cM is one that AncestryDNA's Timber has filtered out.